# What does "421 is the smallest prime formed by the powers of two in logical order from right to left" mean and if so is it correct?

Tags: prime-numbers, terminology

I've seen this on number gossip and a few other places, but I'm not exactly sure what it means. The only possibilities I have thought of for what they mean are "421 is the smallest center squared number that is also prime" which is incorrect as 5 is the smallest center squared prime or that 
$$
A\ ={\large \{ } \sum_ j^k 2^j\ :\ j<k\ ,\ \{j,k\} \in {\bf Z^*} {\large \}}
\\
P = \{2,3,5,7,11, \dots\}
\\
\exists q\in\{A\cup P\}:\forall p\in \{A\cup P\}\ , q\leq  p
\\q=421
$$
Which is also incorrect as $$3\in A \because \sum_{j=0}^{k=1}2^j = 3\\ \because 3\in P\ \ ,\  3 < 421\\ q\neq 421\\\because \forall n\in {\bf Z^*}\ , \  \nexists n :   0<n<1\\ \because \forall a\in A\ ,\ 3\leq a\ ,\nexists a :a<3\\\therefore q=3$$
Does anyone here know what they mean by that?

Comment: It means you tack the first three powers of 2 together from right to left to get the number. If it's prime it has to be the smallest one because $1$ and $21$ are not prime.

Comment: probably meant lexical rather than logical; or reverse lexical, really.

Comment: Yes, it's just the digits 1, 2, 4. One of the most boring 'mathematical' truths I've ever seen! I can't think why people would be posting it on the internet.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently the pattern they are referring to is

$2^0\cdot 1=1$ is not prime

$2^1\cdot10+2^0\cdot 1=21$ is not prime

$2^2\cdot100+2^1\cdot10+2^0\cdot1=421$ is prime.

Im not sure why this is the "logical order from left to right" but it is *some* logical order.